# How do you use mobx with react rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, mobx

While trying to use [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails), I've been running into issues incorporating `mobx` as state management into my app.

I was under the impression that the rails asset pipeline would bring in mobx to react, but, this hasn't been successful. I'm using the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and trying to incorporate mobx into my react.es6.jsx sheets in the components folder.

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "rent-pseudo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "== Zipqode",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.3.18",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "bourbon-neat": "^1.8.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "graphql": "^0.6.2",
    "mobx": "2.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^3.5.3",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.5",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-google-maps": "^4.11.0",
    "react-router": "2.6.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "fetch": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://alexung@github.com/alexung/rent-pseudo.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/alexung/rent-pseudo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/alexung/rent-pseudo#readme"
}
```

My first react file that's included in `/components`:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

const SearchResultsLayout = observer(React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, World</h1>
    )
  }
}))
```

But I keep getting the error `VM3275:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: SearchResultsLayout is not defined`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need this `package.json` file? I think `react-rails` does not require them.

Comment: `SearchResultsLayout is not defined` sounds like `mobx` itself is working (otherwise you would get an `observer not defined`). Is the import statement on your call site of the component correct?

Comment: @mweststrate Hello!  Love mobX btw -- I'm doing work in it on a project at my company, but this is more for my own personal thing.  I'm actually a big naive as to how to how to import things into rails. What I'm doing for React is using the [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) which creates a component folder where i can place my react files.  I am confused as to how to incorporate mobx into this, however.  When i do try including an observer, i do get the ```observer not defined``` error.

Comment: I really have no clue. Zero experience with rails, the answers below are probably more useful ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in knowing, the [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) gem is better for incorporating mobx.  Got it to work this morning by simply installing the gem and npm installing mobx into my `package.json` that's included in the `client` folder

Comment: I created a boilerplate for using rails, react and mobx.
https://github.com/ankitsinghaniyaz/react-rails-mobx-boilerplate

Comment: Thanks @AnkitSinghaniya!

Comment: how would you pass any parameters from rails to mobx observable variables?

Comment: They can be passed in the props object of the react_component (i.e. react_component('Test', props: { dummy: your_rails_instance_var_here }), and then you'll receive them on the react side as this.props.dummy.  From there, you can instantiate a mobx observable var with this.props.dummy

Comment: if You mobx observer var it's in a separate function, you need to wrap your react component in a generator function and initialize mobx store with rails parameters see https://github.com/ankitsinghaniyaz/react-rails-mobx-boilerplate/pull/2/commits/2e8b85b64a49bb5a0e99fe59aeaf62c3bb3f25c6

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you either didn't declare React inside your jsx file via

`import React from 'react'`

or mobx package did not install

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- but where do i declare this?  And I've downloaded the mobx package denoted below to no avail.

Comment: When i try importing at the top of my jsx files, i get ```VM9182:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: [insert component name] is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mobX` from rails assets.
https://rails-assets.org/#/?query=mobx

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried including this gem in my gemfile and then calling an observer again from my react file but was unable to get results, i'm still getting the `SearchResultsLayout.js?body=1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: observer is not defined` error.  The gem also doesn't have explicit instructions about how to include assets.  What are further steps from simply including the gem in my gemfile?

Comment: Did you require mobX in your application.js?

Comment: Can you be more explicit with your suggestion?  How do I require it? a //= require mobx breaks my page.